# Not able to to MTable.getTables.list

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I wrote this very simple code which I saw in many places on the internet

```
import scala.slick.driver.H2Driver.simple._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import slick.jdbc.meta._
import scala.concurrent._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object Helper {
  def printTableNames() : Unit = {
    val db = Database.forConfig("test1")
    db.withSession {implicit session =>
      val x = Await.result(MTable.getTables().list(), Duration.Inf).toList
      x.foreach(println)
    }
  }
}
```

But this gives me a cryptic error at runtime

```
[error] /Users/abhi/ScalaProjects/SlickTest/src/test/scala/HelloSpec.scala:13: overloaded method value getTables with alternatives:
[error]   => slick.profile.BasicStreamingAction[Vector[slick.jdbc.meta.MTable],slick.jdbc.meta.MTable,slick.dbio.Effect.Read] <and>
[error]   (namePattern: String)slick.profile.BasicStreamingAction[Vector[slick.jdbc.meta.MTable],slick.jdbc.meta.MTable,slick.dbio.Effect.Read] <and>
[error]   (cat: Option[String],schemaPattern: Option[String],namePattern: Option[String],types: Option[Seq[String]])slick.profile.BasicStreamingAction[Vector[slick.jdbc.meta.MTable],slick.jdbc.meta.MTable,slick.dbio.Effect.Read]
[error]  cannot be applied to ()
[error]       val x = Await.result(MTable.getTables().list(), Duration.Inf).toList
[error]                                   ^
[error] one error found
[error] (test:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Jun 27, 2015 12:34:03 AM
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
  val x = Await.result(MTable.getTables().list(), Duration.Inf).toList
```

should be

```
  val x = Await.result(MTable.getTables(), Duration.Inf).toList
```

Also x will fetch you a List of MTable something like

```
List(
  MTable(MQName(TEST.PUBLIC.arguments),TABLE,,None,None,None)
  ...
)
```

from which you can get the names, if you require only the names.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are three `getTables` methods all of which do not match `getTables()`. Probably you're trying the `getTables` one (without the parenthesis)?

With that, you'd then call just `list` (not `list()`). Slick definition for list:

```
/** Execute the statement and return an immutable and fully materialized list of the results. */
final def list(implicit session: JdbcBackend#Session) = build[List[R]]
```

shows how there's no non-implicit parameter list.  Therefore you want `list` rather than `list()`.

BUT... I see that the returned object is a stream, implying that `getTables` returns a stream (`db.stream` rather than `db.run`). If you want the list, rather than a stream, cut out this unnecessary step and use `db.run` instead.

Putting all that together, this should work, assuming you want to use the stream (given what I know so far):

```
 Await.result(MTable.getTables, Duration.Inf).toList
```

(PS, it'd help if you mention the version of Slick you were using. Slick 3 very different to older versions.)